# is ".value" an attribute of input element?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

```
return (
      <input 
        type="text" 
        placeholder="Type a color"
        onChange={(e)=> {
          changeColor(e.target.value)
        }}
        ></input>
  )
```

While I was studying React, I saw this code above, and I could not fully understand why I am able to display value typed into the input element. (I didn't put HTML file this time).
I know "e" is an event and by using target property, it's referencing the object, but what is ".value" in this case? I saw one website says it is HTML DOM property, which specifies the value of the attribute, but is it HTML DOM property for input element or something else? I appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, HTML `input` element has a `value` attribute. You can set it to have a default text appear in the input on page load.

You correctly mentioned `e` is an event object. It has an attribute `target` which is the element that created this event. So in your case `e.target.value` refers correctly to the value of the `input` element whos value changed.

Comment: I got it! Thank you for the detailed explanation!! Arigato!

Answer (score 0):

`value` is an attribute for `input` tag as seen from here in [W3 Documentation](http://document.querySelector(%22#wmd-input%22)).

You are correct that `e` is an event, and by using `target` property, you are able to determine the element that caused the event.

Further reading about this can be seen in [FreeCodeCamp](https://www.freecodecamp.org/forum/t/how-works-event-target-value/230553). I recommend doing so, and you will see the most common use of this practice.

Comment: Thank you Zirc!! Now I'm clear why I'm getting this value!!